# How parse answer from backend to React.js?

Tags: reactjs

please give example how can I post JSON by React to API backend, and parse answer from API in React, (for example Message=ok).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is an article which might help you to understand the basics and best practices.

https://dev.to/adyasha8105/how-to-manage-api-calls-in-react-11a8

After reading that, you can follow this one:

https://betterprogramming.pub/clean-api-call-with-react-hooks-3bd6438a375a

For post requests, you can go through this:
https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/02/01/react-fetch-http-post-request-examples